# How to find average of Duplicate Column Headers in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in this format

```
val_id  01/01/2019 01/01/2019 01/02/2019  01/02/2019  01/02/2019 ................ 12/31/2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
v001     56.45        55.11    NAN          NAN        20                          19.1
v002     12.1          NAN     19.1         NAN        45.1                        16
```

How to convert average daily data for each val_id from this data i have